# Upload an image that comes as an encoded string from a post request to S3 with rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rest, amazon-s3, paperclip, decode

I have a model called Picture with an attached file on it.
the software I am using:

```
*Rails 3
*Ruby 1.9.3
*Paperclip
*ImageMagick
```

My model is:

```
class Picture < ActiveRecord::Base
    attr_accessible :picturefile,:picturefile_file_name,:picturefile_content_type,:picturefile_file_size,:picturefile_updated_at
    has_attached_file :picturefile,
    :styles => {
        :thumb=> "100x100#"},
        :storage => :s3,
        :s3_credentials => Rails.root.join('config','s3.yml'),
        :path => "/travels/:style/:id/:basename.:extension"
end
```

And in my controller I have this:

```
StringIO.open(Base64.decode64(params[:Route][:CoverPicture][:File][:EncodedContent])) do |data|
fotocov_t=Picture.create({
  :picturefile=>data
})
travel.pictures = [fotocov_t] #this assigns the new picture to a travel i created before the picture
end
```

As it can be seen i am uploading a string, but what I want to upload is an image that is made by the encoded string in

```
params[:Route][:CoverPicture][:File][:EncodedContent]
```

I have tried with multiple aproaches but keeps saving a text file.

Does anyone know how I can upload the file as an image instead of uploading a textfile?

Thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it :)

```
bytes = Base64.decode64(params[:Route][:CoverPicture][:File][:EncodedContent])
img   = Magick::Image.from_blob(bytes).first
```

On record creation:

```
:picturefile=>img
```

Needed rmagick.
Now I have another trouble with No handler for...

But will be searching and uploading info :)

Comment: Made it complete!

Used rmagick to obtain format:

    bytes = Base64.decode64(params[:Route][:CoverPicture][:File][:EncodedContent])
    img   = Magick::Image.from_blob(bytes).first

After that:

    data=StringIO.new(Base64.decode64(~~~~)
    data.class.class_eval { attr_accessor :original_filename, :content_type }
    data.original_filename = "cover."+fmt
    data.content_type = "image/"+fmt

And:

    :picturefile=>data